# Android ui programming

Tags: android

I am a novice Android programmer. I am creating an app in which I am using radio group and a button.

When the button is clicked the background color changes as per the selected radiobutton. If the radiobutton is not selected and button is clicked, the app collapses. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This website should get you started.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

You'll have to download Eclipse and the Android SDK from Google. This is the native route. There are many ways to create an Android app. If you're familiar with HTML and Javascript, use your web programming skills to create Android apps. http://phonegap.com/ is a nice framework and it's very popular for this. You get tons of help from thousands of programmers.